# .Net Array() is the same as []

Tags: c#, .net

Silly question, but one I must ask as I am trying to create a System.Collections.Big assembly, filled with various collections that use larger indexes.

So, confirm if I am correct, the Array() class is not a simple wrapper for arrays([]) in C#, but is the real deal, correct? So if I upgrade Array to use a larger indexer, I can use the [] operator to get / set things without fear of some hidden nastiness, right?

Comment: How exactly do you intend to upgrade Array?

Comment: @Oded It will probably have an indexer which takes a [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) instance and do the array management under the covers (using smaller arrays).  Although I'd question just how large you need an array to be given that you can use a `long` as an indexer.

Comment: @casperOne - My understanding of the question is that the OP wants to extend `Array` and was hoping that would translate to getting array declarations (using  `new type[]`) to then be `long` indexable.

Comment: @Oded Yeah, you and I both know that's not possible.  Unless you do something with say, Roslyn which compiles array declarations into this, but that's going *way* outside the bounds of what's reasonable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right that `Array` implements `[]`, but you cannot extend it.

That is, even though `Array` is not sealed, you cannot derive from it -- the system will not let you. So you cannot modify `Array`'s indexing mechanism either.

But why would you want to do that anyway?

**EDIT** `BigArray<T>` already exists in the .NET Framework :-), see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshwil/archive/2005/08/10/450202.aspx

Comment: A number of us need 64-bit goodness for special apps that require that kind of memory. In my case, an evolutionary program.

Comment: Then you would have to simulate array behavior by creating a custom class, say `BigArray`, with multiple arrays under the hood...

Comment: Hmm. I am actually thinking about just implementing the new array in C++, then using DllImport to link it to C#. That should side-step the managed maximum size, hopefully.